# help for Url detection regex

Tags: regex

I hope this question is not a duplicate but I didn't find anything equivalent on SO.

I want a regex for checking an URL.

The given URL can be local `/some-text` or external `http://theurl`

I am trying `^http://|/[-\w/\.]+$` but it doesn't work.

I don't know how to write the optional `http://`. Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
^(https?://|/)[\w/.-]+$
```

or, if you care about `//` at the begining:

```
^(https?://|/)[^/]+[\w/.-]*$
```

Comment: @luc: Try what I have now. You probably want to just use `.+`, though.

Comment: I am using ^(https?://\w|/)[\w/.-]*$ Thanks for your help.